# JQuery unwrap content

Tags: jquery, html

Within a CMS I am working on a blog. The HTML structure of the output for each post title looks like this:

```
<h2>
    <a href="...">Title</a>
</h2>
```

What I want to do is remove the `<a>` tag that wraps the content representing the blog title.

I did a bit of looking around and found 2 almost-solutions:

1. `remove()` - this will remove the content itself too though
2. `unwrap()` - I don't think you can target text within a tag with this to get rid of the tag itself.

Comment: The best solution is the updated answer from Gaby aka G. Petrioli, not the checked solution. Check it out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`.wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) first and unwrap the new structure..

```
$('h2 a').wrapInner('<span>').children().unwrap();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ffKDn/

---

**Updating with a better way ..**

Use the [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to target the text nodes and use `.unwrap()` on those..

```
$('h2 a').contents().unwrap();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ffKDn/8/

Answer (score 1):

This would be achieved much more efficiently by editing the appropriate template within the CMS.  But you can accomplish it with the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2').each(function() {
       $(this).html($(this).children().html());
    });
});
```

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cheeken/TRpbR/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove()` but first you need to capture the text.  So something like this

```
var title = $('h2 a').text();
//grab the text from the a href

$('h2').remove('a');
//remove the link    

$('h2').html(title);
//add the title back to the h2
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qzHsb/

Comment: This solution fails if there are multiple `h2 a` elements, because all titles have the same text applied.

Comment: Of course...@cheeken.  But the OP said this is the output for *each* post.  There wouldn't be more than one title for each post.  At least, that's the way I answered it.

Comment: This seems most logical to me - and yes, there will only be one instance of h2 per post :)

Comment: I am just accustomed to there being multiple posts on blog pages (such as on the front page).  But I'm glad this answer is useful!

Comment: No, it was a good point @cheeken.  I was just following what I thought I read.  In any event, the code could have been moved into an `.each()` if needed.  Cheers.